# BeautifulSoup, браузер не поддерживается

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

В попытке парсинга текста с сайта Youtube Music, в парсер лезет лишь страница с текстом :

> Приложение YouTube Music не поддерживается в вашем браузере. Обновите его или установите Google Chrome

Можно ли решить данную проблему?
Вот код самой программы:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def takeHTML(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def getLink(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    d = soup.find_all('div')
    #head = soup.find('a', class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string")
    print(d)

getLink(takeHTML('https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_n1xp8llRUpMLfFAnKJlwdAN5M9oqFUiFA'))
```

Comment: Selenium скорее всего придётся использовать, сейчас модно сайты через JavaScript генерить, а не готовые страницы отдавать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего библиотека requests выдаёт вас, как парсер или представляется серверу как какой-то устаревший браузер. Чтобы сказать requests как представляться, нужно указать дополнительные параметры в вашем запросе. Вам нужно в параметре `headers` указать словарь с нужными нам настройками. Чтобы представиться другим браузером нужно указать значение `User-Agent`. Чтобы сгенерировать эту информацию установите модуль [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) и потом какое-либо поле класса `UserAgent`. Лучше всего `UserAgent.chrome()` Ниже ваш исправленный код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


def takeHTML(url):
    ua = UserAgent()
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ua.firefox})
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def getLink(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    d = soup.find_all('div')
    #head = soup.find('a', class_="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string")
    print(d)

getLink(takeHTML('https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_n1xp8llRUpMLfFAnKJlwdAN5M9oqFUiFA'))
```

Не забудьте установить [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)

Comment: Если, я вам помог, то поставьте галочку пожалуйста, если нет, то обратитесь ко мне в комментарии. Может я что-то забыл

Comment: А вы пробовали, у вас работает? Во-первых вы user-agent неправильно передаёте, во-вторых ошибка та же самая получается.

Comment: Поправил я вам User-agent, так не ругается, но и по сути ничего не показывает - там похоже реально JS сплошной и нужен Selenium